# Build successive condition to when

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to build a sql request of consecutive `when`.

```
def build_modify_function(df, ids_colname, modified_colname, modification_list):
if len(modification_list) == 0:
    pass
# Small optimization
id_col      = df[ids_colname]
modif_col   = df[modified_colname]
# There is no "identity element" so :
ret = None
for (row_ids, new_value) in modification_list:
    if type(row_ids) != type(list()):
        row_ids = list(row_ids)
    if ret == None:
        ret = when(id_col.isin(row_ids), new_value) # .isin(row_ids)
    else:
        ret = ret.when(id_col.isin(row_ids), new_value)
return modif_col if ret == None else ret.otherwise(modif_col)
```

`df` is a dataframe,

`ids_colname` is the column name of my ids,

`modified_colname` is the column name I want to modify,

`modification_list` is a list of tuple `[(list_of_ids, new_value)]`

I am having this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: 
please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

I don't understand why. When I build a very simple function returning :

```
 tmp = when(id_col.isin(row_ids), new_value)
 return tmp\
     .when(id_col.isin(row_ids), new_value)\
     .otherwise(modif_col)
```

It perfectly works. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the problem is here:

```
if ret == None:
   ...
```

In general you should never use equality operators to compare to singleton objects in Python and always use `is` or `is not`:

```
if ret is None:
    ...
```

In this particular case equality operator for column returns a `Column` and `Column` object explicitly forbids conversion to bool.